# How can i extract a word to a specific column and row by imacros code

Tags: csv, imacros

I want to write a word in a specific column and row by iMacros code. For example, I want to extract (write) `Hello` to column 6 and row 8.

This code below writes this word in the first column and row 1. I tried many ways but it doesn't work for me.

```
SET !DATASOURCE C:\job\test.csv
ADD !EXTRACT Hello
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\job\ FILE=test.csv
```

Comment: Helloo Stackoverflow engineers

Comment: i don't use it in a specific website, i just want to use it as a logs script, i want to write Hello in specific column and row in test.csv 
the code above if you run it it will write hello in first column and first row